# installing the Facebook module into Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have tried a few way to install the Facebook module but for some reason i am getting this error:

```
/AndroidProjects/FacebookExample/facebook/build.gradle
 Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':Facebook'.
```

i followed the instructions given as:

-Download the Facebook SDK from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/
-Unzip the archive
-In Android Studio 0.5.5 or later, choose "Import Module" from the File menu.
-In the wizard, set the source path of the module to import as the "facebook" directory inside the
    unpacked archive. (Note: If you choose the entire parent folder, it will bring in not only the
    library itself, but also all of the sample apps, each as a separate module. This may work but
    probably isn't what you want).
-You should be good to go.

is there something more i need to edit for the module to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By importing the "facebook" module, you are not bringing in the files at the root of the facebook sdk.
The file "gradle.properties" defines 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION'.  Copy that file into the root of your project.

Comment: because i am very new to android and importing modules, if i had imported the whole sdk folder would that have been better? just curious how all this works.

Comment: The sdk folder appears to be a project, so you would probably want to use the "import project" option and select the SDK folder itself.  Modules that don't have a dependency on something in the project can just be imported as modules.

Comment: is there something i need to install before i import the module? i am getting a new error--  Error:Cause: failed to find target android-20 : /Users/user/Android Development/android-sdk-macosx
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>

Comment: That means you haven't installed the SDK for API level 20 which the facebook project is looking for.  Just go to "Tools->Android->SDK Manager" and download "SDK Platform" for API 20.

Comment: there is no such file "gradle.properties"